# Gatsby GraphQL not getting image from Strapi 4

Tags: gatsby, strapi

I'm using Strapi v.4 , Gatsby v.4.25.7 , gatsby-source-strapi v 3.2.0
My settings in gatsby-config.js looks like this

```
const strapiConfig = {
  apiURL: process.env.STRAPI_API_URL,
  accessToken: process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
  collectionTypes: [
    'article',
    'category',
    'tag',
    'author',
    {
      singularName: 'article',
      queryParams: {
        populate: {
          image: '*',
          author: {
            populate: {
              picture: '*',
            },
          },
          blocks: {
            populate: {
              image: '*',
            },
          }
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  singleTypes: ['homepage', 'global'],
  queryLimit: 1000,
}
```

I have a work request that returns an image (blocks.image)
/api/articles?populate[0]=blocks&populate[1]=author.picture,blocks.image&filters[slug][$eq]=statya-dlya-testa-dinamicheskoj-zony-opublikovannaya

but when I explore Strapi GraphQL I cant see images data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR5Hn.png)

my strapi settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5usB.png)

i try use

```
blocks: {
  populate: {
     image: '*',
  },
}
// or
  blocks: {
     populate: '*',
  }
// or
populate: ['blocks', 'blocks.image']
```

i build my project after every try and clean cache